# Below given circuit, when given 24V DC supply for 30 seconds, the IN5408 diode shorts out at a rate of 1 in 5 cases

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, dc, flyback, electromagnetic

[image]

With circuit given below, when given 24V DC supply for 30 seconds, the IN5408 diode shorts out at a rate of 1 in 5 cases. This is an EMR circuit.

What could be the possible cause for this issue?

Comment: That depends on the  light load total impedance.  (uF  and stored energy)  and the contact bounce of the relay and any possible miswiring resonance.  Show more details of every part.

Comment: You've drawn the 30A load as inductive.  Even with the freewheel diode, it may be producing enough of a pulse to fry the 1N5408 when it's disconnected.

Comment: maybe the diode on the inductor isn't fast enough ?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to prevent this failure ? Can I add a resistor in series with the IN5408 Diode? Will it prevent the IN5408 from getting burnt?

Comment: Is it possible for the free wheeling current to pass through the IN5408? As per my designer,he says it's not possible for the free wheeling current to flow through IN5408 and that it will only flow through the free wheeling diode. And one more information is both the diodes in discussion are general purpose diodes. None is fast recovery diode

Comment: If  free wheeling current can pass through the in5408 diode ? Do the voltage drop of both the diodes is off any significance? Because IN5408 voltage drop is around 0.2v while the free wheeling diodes voltage drop is of 0.5v

Comment: Is that really +/ 24V so 48V system, or simply +24V and 0V return so 14V system?